# obscure but great intellectuals

Tags: meaning

I need to find a term for those scholars and intellectuals who are relatively obscure but who many colleagues consider to be great or near-great

Comment: If  ***many*** colleagues consider them to be great or near-great, that would imply they'd also be relatively well-known. But putting that aside, perhaps consider ***unsung** [heroes]* or ***oft-overlooked***, for example).

Comment: *Hidden gems* (of broad application).

Answer (score 3):

You might call this type of person an **X's X**.

"Jane Smith isn't very well-known, but she's a mathematician's mathematician."

"Some people might not get his humor, but John Smith is a comedian's comedian."

This means that this person is not well-known by the public, but is popular among people in that particular field.